# explode new line in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How do I convert the php code below into javascript? I google it and found something to do with st.replace(/,/g,"\n") but how to apply it to the variable? I have low knowledge about javascript and trying to learn it.

```
$items = explode("\n", $model);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

```
items = model.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you are searching for [[*String*]`.split("\n")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which returns an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) you found would be similiar to `implode("\n", explode(",", $model))`.

Answer (score 3):

The basically equivalent code is:

```
var model = 'some string...';
var items = model.split('\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourArray = [];
var yourString = 'a,b,c,d,e';
yourArray = yourString.split(',');
```

Comment: No need to set yourArray to [].